# My custom POST Controller return empty response

Tags: magento2, controllers, response, post

I created my custom Controller for POST request, but i all time have empty response.

```
    $testIds = $this->request->getPost('test');
    $items = [];
    foreach ($testIds as $id) {
        $items[$id] = [
            'test' => $id,
        ];
    }

    if (count($items)) {
        $response = [
            'success'   => true,
            'items'     => $items
        ];
    } else {
        $response = [
            'success'   => false,
            'message'   => __('False')
        ];
    }

    (Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory)
    $resultJson = $this->jsonFactory->create();
    $resultJson->setData($response);

    return $resultJson;
```

My Controller implements Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPostActionInterface.

How i can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

In general, HTTP responses of 500 will write an error to the Magento log if it is a Magento issue, and will not write to the Magento log if it is not a Magento issue. So first check the log:

```
$ cd /path/to/magento/installation
$ tail var/log/system.log
```

This is an answer to the general case of "Why am I getting 500 response". Once you know the answer to that question, you can start to debug the specific issue being faced.

Comment: Thank you. I just wanted to make an update on the issue, because I found the reason for the 500 code. I found the reason for 500 code. Sometimes my conditions were not met and the post request was not transmitted, so a 500 error occurred